# URL rewrite not working when am importing a file

Tags: php, apache

This might seem like a duplicate question but I've looked through all similar questions and none seemed to solve my problem. I am fairly new to php and I recently made all request to my site to pass through the index.php file by editing the .htaccess file, if the user enters `localhost/questions/mcq.php?course_id=31` the index file then imports from `view/questions/mcq.php`. I then attempted url rewrite with .htaccess with this line

```
RewriteRule ^questions/mcq/([0-9]+)$ /view/questions/mcq.php?course_id=$1 [NC]
```

I also tried

```
RewriteRule ^questions/mcq/([0-9]+)$ /questions/mcq.php?course_id=$1 [NC]
```

when I enter `localhost/questions/mcq/31` I get this error

```
Warning: require_once(C:/xampp/htdocs/view/questions/mcq/31): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\resources\library\classes\template-class.php on line 25

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:/xampp/htdocs/view/questions/mcq/31' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\resources\library\classes\template-class.php on line 25
```

I will like to know what I am doing wrong and any help will be greatly appreciated.

(edit)
here is the full .htaccess codes

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.png$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.jpg$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.jpeg$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.css$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.gif$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.js$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?route=/$1 [QSA,L]
# RewriteRule ^questions/mcq/([0-9]+)?$ /view/questions/mcq.php?course_id=$1 [NC, L]
RewriteRule ^questions/mcq/([0-9]+)$ /view/questions/mcq.php?course_id=$1 [R=301, L]
```

Comment: Why there is a `/` before `$1` in line `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?route=/$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: Also, try `RewriteBase /` after line `RewriteEngine on`

Comment: I put it there because my index file is located in the root. I tried it with `/index.php` and `index.php` and both worked

Comment: `/` after `route=` which is `route=/$1`?

Comment: I'm thinking the problem happens because when I enter `localhost/questions/mcq/31`  the index file takes it and then requires the file `view/questions/mcq/31` meaning that apache never gets the chance to convert the url to `view/questions/mcq.php?course_id=31` before the import request is made.

Comment: I think the problem is in line `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?route=/$1 [QSA,L]` and thats why it throw an error

Comment: I just commented it out now and the same error still happens. It does not report server when I remove the last 2 lines except the error that php throws when it fails to import `view/questions/mcq/31`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteRule ^questions/mcq/([0-9]+)$ /view/questions/mcq.php?course_id=$1 [R=301,L]
```

**EDIT**
Try this code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.png$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.jpg$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.jpeg$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.css$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.gif$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.js$ [NC]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^questions/mcq/([0-9]+)$ /view/questions/mcq.php?course_id=$1 [NC,END]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?route=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I just tried it now and I got server error (error 500)

Comment: I just deleted my .htaccess file and created a new one with your code and it still shows server error (error 500). I'm grateful for the time your taking to help me.

Comment: I've placed this `.htaccess` file in the root directory (www) in created file `mcq.php` inside `www/view/questions/` and above code worked for me. Hope you figure out the problem.